# Javascript multiple var arrays

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I have the following bit of javascript that blocks off dates in a calendar and displays a message instead:

```
var unavailableDates = ["28-7-2017", "29-7-2017", "30-7-2017", "31-7-2017", "28-8-2017", "24-12-2017", "25-12-2017", "26-12-2017", "1-1-2018", "30-3-2018", "31-3-2018", "1-4-2018", "1-2-2018", "7-5-2018", "28-5-2018", "6-8-2018", "27-8-2018", "24-12-2018", "25-12-2018", "26-12-2018", "1-1-2019"];
jQuery(function($) {
$("#Booking1arrivaldate").datepicker({
    minDate: 5,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Closed to the public for drop off and collection."];
        }
    }
});
});
```

If someone tries to select one of the dates within the var unavailableDates  then it won't let them and instead displays the message.

However I need to add another var with a completely different message if those dates are selected. I have tried a few combinations of the if statement but keep getting errors in my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please explain the [tag:contact-form-7] on this

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle or a demo snippet?